# Empty File Output

Tags: python, html, json, debugging, file-io

I am very new and need your help. I want to write a script I can generalize to do web-scraping. So far I have the code below, but it keeps giving me a blank output file. I would like to be able to easily modify this code to work on all websites and eventually be able to make the search strings a little more complex. For now, I have CNN as a general page, and "mccarthy" b/c I figure there are certainly articles with him in them right now. Can you help me get this to work?

```
#Begin Code
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import docx

# Set the search parameters
search_term = 'mccarthy'  # Set the search term
start_date = '2023-01-04'  # Set the start date (format: YYYY-MM-DD)
end_date = '2023-01-05'  # Set the end date (format: YYYY-MM-DD)
website = 'https://www.cnn.com'  # Set the website to search
document = open('testfile.docx','w')  # Open the existing Word document

# Initialize the list of articles and the page number
articles = []
page_number = 1

# Set the base URL for the search API
search_url = f'{website}/search'

# Set the base URL for the article page
article_base_url = f'{website}/article/'

while articles or page_number == 1:
    # Send a request to the search API
    response = requests.get(search_url, params={'q': search_term, 'from': start_date, 'to': end_date,     'page': page_number})

    # Check if the response is in JSON format
    if response.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        # Load the JSON data
        data = response.json()

        # Get the list of articles from the JSON data
        articles = data['articles']
    else:
        # Parse the HTML content of the search results page
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        # Find all articles on the search results page
        articles = soup.find_all('article')

    # Loop through the articles
    for article in articles:
        # Find the link element
        link_element = article.find('a', class_='title')

        # Extract the link from the link element
        link = link_element['href']

        # Check if the link is a relative URL
        if link.startswith('/'):
            # If the link is relative, convert it to an absolute URL
            link = f'{website}{link}'

        # Add the link to the document
        document.add_paragraph(link)

    # Increment the page number
    page_number += 1

# Save the document
document.close()
```

I have tried numerous iterations, but I have deleted them all so cannot really post any here. This keeps giving me a blank output file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, trace through **what actually happens** when you try running your code, and identify a **concrete, specific** problem. For example, did the loop `while articles or page_number == 1:` get entered? If so, what does the result for `response` look like? How about the result for `response.headers['Content-Type']`? Did `articles` end containing something that looks right?

Comment: Make sure you have a **concrete expectation** for each step of the code (that is the primary thing that separates *writing code* from typing arbitrary text into an editor), and then **verify** where your expectation is not met. This will allow you to ask a properly **specific** question, which starts with creating a [mre] based on your findings.

Answer (score -1):

This won't solve the main issue but a couple of things to fix:

https://edition.cnn.com/search?q=&from=0&size=10&page=1&sort=newest&types=all&section=

Looking at the CNN search page URL, we can see that the from parameter is not referring to a date but a number instead, i.e. if from=5, it will only show the 5th article onwards. Therefore you can remove 'from' and 'to' from your request params.

> articles = soup.find_all('article')

This is returning an empty list because there are no <article> tags within the HTML page. Inspecting the [CNN HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz1jE.png) we see that the URLs you are looking for are within <div class="card container__item container__item--type- __item __item--type- "> tags so I would change this line to `soup.find_all('div', class_="card container__item container__item--type- __item __item--type- ")`

> document = open('testfile.docx','w')  # Open the existing Word document

You've imported the docx module but are not using it. Word documents (which require extra data for formatting) should be opened like this `document = Document()`. For reference, here are the docx docs: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> while articles or page_number == 1:

I don't think this line is needed.

The main issue seems to be that this page requires Javascript to be run to render the content. Using request.get() by itself won't do this. You'll need to  use a library such as [Requests-HTML](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/). I tried doing this but the articles still don't render so I'm not sure.

Comment: Please read [answer] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We don't want answers that offer "a couple things to fix" and explicitly don't address "the main issue". If it isn't clear what or where that issue is, **do not attempt to answer** - it is OP's responsibility to clarify these matters first. Questions that are missing debugging details or lack focus (i.e., the OP has not put in the effort to identify a specific thing that goes wrong when the code runs, compared to expectation) should be closed, not answered.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).